# How to get the name of current opened application in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-custom-keyboard

I have developed a custom keyboard and its sending stickers and gifs alright but the problem which is occurring is that whatsapp supports 512x512px stickers only and my mobile's massenger supports 420x420 stickers so, HOW do I know which app is currently running besides my custom keyboard so that I could send the correctly formatted stickers. Any help is appreciated and if any other approach might be viable so please do tell. Thank you

I have tried numerous things but some code only give the name which is on top of the stack which in this case is my keyboard but I cant get the name of current opened massenger app's name